# How to calculate compound interest annually, semi-annually, quarterly, monthly and daily?

Tags: java

```
public class interest {

    public void calculate(int principle, int year, double interestRate, int terms) {
        double sinterest = ((500000 * 3.5 * 10) / 100);
        double amount = principle * Math.pow(1 + (interestRate / terms), terms * year);
        double cinterest = amount - principle;

        System.out.println("Simple interest on Taka. 500000.00 in " + year + " years = Taka "+sinterest);
        System.out.println("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in " + year + " years compounded annually = Taka. "+cinterest);
        System.out.println("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in " + year + " years compounded semi-annually = Taka. "+cinterest);
        System.out.println("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in " + year + " years compounded quarterly = Taka. "+cinterest);
        System.out.println("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in " + year + " years compounded monthly = Taka. "+cinterest);
        System.out.println("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in " + year + " years compounded daily = Taka. "+cinterest);


        
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        interest obj = new interest();
        obj.calculate(500000, 10, 0.035, 4); //principle: 500000, year: 10, interest: 0.035, terms: 4
    }
}
```

*current output:*

```
Simple interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years = Taka 175000.0
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded annually = Taka. 208454.41896556818
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded semi-annually = Taka. 208454.41896556818
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded quarterly = Taka. 208454.41896556818
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded monthly = Taka. 208454.41896556818
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded daily = Taka. 208454.41896556818
```

**All compounded interest (annually, semi-annually, quarterly, monthly and daily) printing same value(quarterly = Taka. 208454.42). It should be different as the expected output.**

Expected output:

```
Simple interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years = Taka. 175000.00
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded annually = Taka. 205299.38
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded semi-annually = Taka. 207389.10
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded quarterly = Taka. 208454.42
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded monthly = Taka. 209172.41
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded daily = Taka. 209521.87
```

**

> Do I have to add this line more and update the "term" value?

**

```
obj.calculate(500000, 10, 0.035, 4); //principle: 500000, year: 10, interest: 0.035, terms: 4
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what do you need.

Comment: You calculate ```cinterest``` one time and then print it out five different times without changing it, so it's certainly going to print the same value each time.

Comment: The thing you are doing is just discouraging me. But I'm unstoppable

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void calculate(int principle, int year, double interestRate) {
    double sinterest = principle * interestRate * year;
    Function<Integer, Double> interest = terms -> principle * Math.pow(1 + (interestRate / terms), terms * year) - principle;

    System.out.printf("Simple interest on Taka. 500000.00 in %d years = Taka %.2f%n", year, sinterest);
    System.out.printf("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in %d years compounded annually = Taka. %.2f%n", year, interest.apply(1));
    System.out.printf("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in %d years compounded semi-annually = Taka. %.2f%n", year, interest.apply(2));
    System.out.printf("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in %d years compounded quarterly = Taka. %.2f%n", year, interest.apply(4));
    System.out.printf("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in %d years compounded monthly = Taka. %.2f%n", year, interest.apply(12));
    System.out.printf("Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in %d years compounded daily = Taka. %.2f%n", year, interest.apply(365));
}
```

and

```
obj.calculate(500000, 10, 0.035); //principle: 500000, year: 10, interest: 0.035
```

output:

```
Simple interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years = Taka 175000.00
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded annually = Taka. 205299.38
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded semi-annually = Taka. 207389.10
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded quarterly = Taka. 208454.42
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded monthly = Taka. 209172.41
Interest on Taka. 500000.00 in 10 years compounded daily = Taka. 209521.87
```